# Coloring a Nest treemap with D3.JS

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am working on creating a Treemap from a csv file. The data in the csv file is hierarchical and looks like this example that I stole from another Stack Overflow question

```
parent,child,value
Homer Simpson,Bart,20
Homer Simpson,Lisa,14
Homer Simpson,Maggie,6
Peter Griffin,Chris,19
Peter Griffin,Meg,12
Peter Griffin,Stewie,9
```

I am using d3.nest(), because I don't want to have to reformat my CSV like [so](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/33). Most of my file was stolen off of Mike Bostock's Nest Treemap [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2838bf53e0e65f369f476afd653663a2), but I can't figure out how to color the parents differently and I'm very new to both Javascript and D3. Here's the script I'm working with

```
<script>

var format = d3.format(",d"),
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.parent;})
    .key(function(d) {return d.child;})
    .rollup(function(d) {return d3.sum(d, function(d) {return d.value;}); });

var treemap = d3.treemap()
    .size([960, 960])
    .round(true)
    .padding(1);

d3.csv("d3.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        if (d.parent == "null") { d.parent = null};
    });

    var root = d3.hierarchy({values: nest.entries(data)}, function(d) { return d.values; })
        .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

    treemap(root);

    var node = d3.select("body")
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(root.leaves())
        .enter().append("div")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .style("left", function(d) { return d.x0 + "px"; })
        .style("top", function(d) { return d.y0 + "px"; })
        .style("width", function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0 + "px"; })
        .style("height", function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0 + "px"; })
        .style("background", function(d) { while (d.depth > 1) d = d.parent; return color(d.id); })

    node.append("div")
        .attr("class", "node-label")
        .text(function(d) { return d.parent.data.key + "\n" + d.data.key; });

    node.append("div")
        .attr("class", "node-value")
        .text(function(d) { return format(d.value); });
});

</script>
```

[image: Here's what happens]

How can I colorize the different blocks? I'm stuck with implementing a background style and don't understand why all parents seem to have the same color. I believe getting the parents correct would help me implement zooming as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no property `d.id` (which you use to set the fill), this returns undefined, and all your elements will be colored the same with the ordinal scale.

To get the identifier of the parent here, we need to look at the `d.data` property, which contains another object:

```
{ 
   key: "Homer Simpson",
   values: [children]
}
```

If you want to color the children based on a parent, use `d.data.key`:

```
.style("background", function(d) { while (d.depth > 1) d = d.parent; return color(d.data.key); })
```